# Measurements and units in svg-edit

Tags: svg, dpi, units

I am doing a modified version of [SVG-edit 2.6 alpha](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/), an online tool that allows the creation of graphics.

I intend to use the application to allow my university students to send files for cutting their project stickers through the web. However the measurements are in pixels and I am worried that the conversion on my side will produce wrong results since from what I understand DPI setting vary from computer to computer and also from browser to browser. In other words I am worried that I cannot ensure compatibility.

I am also worried about fonts. I want to install a number of fonts that my students can use, but I am also worried that font compatibility and measurements will vary from computer to computer and from browser to browser.

I know there is an option to use millimiters now in svg-edit however this option causes a number of bugs in the application and i dont want to use it.

Does anyone have any good expierience with the application and can give me any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Comment: When dealing with magazines, they provide me with a spec. which I must follow so that artwork matches requirements. It is offset press and they know the trim size of the magazine so dpi follows from that specification. For instance: the plates might be 150 line screens, which dictates a sampling rate of about 2x to avoid moire patterns, so 300dpi images are desirable. What are the production limitations for the creation and cutting of a project sticker? Are you using a particular piece of equipment? What are the largest and smallest sizes which can be created on your equipment?

Comment: thank you, my actual problem lies elsewhere, in coreldraw conversions, but i really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Is this actually a separate question to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13162/pixels-in-vectors-svg? As it stands I can't see a real question here.

Comment: let me say again clearer this time.. is there any way if my customers use a different dpi with me that i will get a different size shape in my end. only talking in pixels forget about millimiters..

Comment: I don't see how the shape would change since the aspect ratio of a shape should remain the same in all screen resolutions/dpi values... Since you're coming from application development, I'd recommend that you ask at the [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) (about programming) or the [User Experience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com) of Stackexchange. (Pretty nice application that SVG Edit,  BTW.)