# Adobe Illustrator pixel to mm formula?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I import VECTORS in illustrator that i want to lasercut but they are measured in pixels. I want to output that to DXF. However i am wondering if pixels are converted to mm using a standard formula in Illustrator.

From what i am guessing however Illustrator is set to default DPI at 72 so the formula is standard (pixels*25.4)/dpi. Is this correct? Also is this the standard that Illustrator uses?

If i take this and reverse it i can see that illustrator multiplies the pixels by 2.8347. If i always scale the pixels using 283.47% will i always get the same result in mm? Is there anyway this can go wrong or is it hardwired and non-changeable in Illustrator?

Thank you

Mario

Comment: possibly related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13162/pixels-in-vectors-svg

Comment: thank you but this is not related.

Comment: I don't have AI in front of me, but lots of software does let you change the software's pixel-to-real-measurement formula. If that's an option, then I suppose you can't rely on pixels having a consistent correlation to a real world physical measurement.

Comment: The question DA01 links to describes essentially the same problem - receiving art measured in pixels and needing to convert to real-world measurements.

Comment: Why are you getting artwork for print that is measured in pixels in the first place? This is your real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator doesn't measure anything in pixels primarily because Illustrator, being vector-based, is math-based and a **pixel has no size**.

Illustrator has no "default [PPI]" because it's a vector-based, resolution-independent, application. The only time PPI is used within Illustrator is when placing raster images - in which case the image PPI is used, or creating raster effects - in which case the settings under Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings are used.

Illustrator essentially uses 1 point to equal 1 pixel for measurements. While this is not really accurate and pixels can easily vary in size, this is done to preserve at least *some* logic in the application. Again, because you can't measure a pixel. You'd be better served with a [point to millimeter conversion](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/millimeters-to-points-computer-conversion.html). This is also where you've "guessed" at Illustrator using 72ppi. It's not, it's using points and there are 72 points to an inch. Or 2.834645669 points to a millimeter. That formula which was posted, while accurate for points is **completely** **inaccurate** if referring to pixels.

You can't think of pixels as having a size. They do not. So to answer your question.... no. Because there's no way of determining the size of a pixel without also knowing the width and height of the entire image, as well as the total number of pixels contained in the image.

Comment: However illustrator does measure it right? What you are saying is that illustrator actually gives a size to a pixel created within it. 1 pixel = 1/72 of an inch so its actually hardwired within illustrator. If i create a VECTOR that is 72 pixels in illustrator this will give me a size of 1 inch. As you say then what i understand is that this will ALWAYS be the case in Illustrator since it is hardwired in it.

Comment: Yes but if i create something in illustrator in pixels then it is 1point=1pixel=1/72 of an inch. I am not talking about importing raster images i talked about importing an SVG which is a vector in pixels.

Comment: No, I did not post that Illustrator gives a size to a pixel. It does not. What I posted was Illustrator uses POINTS for measurements. If you measure anything in pixels you are not being accurate and are destined to think of pixels as a unit when it's not. Just because Illustrator uses 1pt = 1px that doesn't mean it's accurate. That pixel could actually measure 4pt x4pt. But again, without width, height, and total pixels there's no way of knowing.

Comment: so if i create a line thats 100pixels length in illustrator how does it calculate its length in mm??

Comment: @MarioJoan then DA01s comment to your question linking tot he other thread is indeed 100% accurate. If you import an SVG document, how do you KNOW that 1 pixel is the same size as 1 point????? You can't, because a pixel is not a unit.

Comment: If you draw a line 100px in length in Illustrator it is 100pts in length and may or may not actually be 100 pixels in length.

Comment: An SVG is a text file right? It says 100 pixels line. I want to take that thing as it is on the text of the svg and convert it to the same number in millimiters. nothing more. i think vectors dont use a DPI what do you think about that. will the conversion be the same or am i still gonna run into a problem?  basically i want to take all measurements that are within an SVG text file in pixels and make them millimiters within illustrator. Then export the sizes in DXF format for laser cutting.

Comment: If all you want is a different measurement unit within Illustrator, right-click/control-click a ruller and choose MM. All measurements will then be read in MM. Let the app do the math. You don't need to convert anything, just change what Illustrator shows you.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that svg files do in fact allow one to specify pixels. This clouds the issue. In many examples, one sets the viewport size to pixel dimensions (usually for the web-based applications), and then uses dimensionless values for the objects and primitives. Set the pasteboard or document to the dimensions and units which you desire the printed product to be, `Place...` the SVG file, and then scale it to fit the pasteboard.

Comment: thats right skaught! if an svg files says in its text that a square for example is 100*100 pixels then thats what it was drawn by the user on his computer. irrespectively of anything. he specified something to be 100*100 pixels and thats it. that square will always be imported in illustrator with the correct number. if i take that square and just change its units to mm then the scaling was done and its now 100*100 mm. i dont need to know any formulas or anything. thank you friends. if you think i still got it wrong just comment me back